# JWT Authentication in Microservices

Tags: java, spring, rest, jwt

I am working on a Spring Rest Microservices Project with 5 microservices with me. I have added JWT Authentication in the User MS and the JWT token in being generated.
Now If I want to call a different microservice, what will be the procedure for authenticating the token for that foreign MS? I tried various sources to study JWT with Microservices but couldn't find any good source. Resources and references are welcome plz.

Comment: The Spring Security documentation is usually very good and I would suggest having a read of it.  From memory, I believe that once the token is authentication and/or authorisation the token is held in the security context, it should, in theory by very simple to forward/attach the token to requests to other services.  If you need to use a JWT with different claims for the other services, its likely better to create a new JWT for the request.  Again it should be possible to retrieve the claims of the JWT from the security context.

Answer (score 1):

you can authenticate the authorization on the api gateway, if you are using Feign, you can use `@RequestHeader` to add the token in the header